# How to make 3D and contour plots from a two variable mathematical function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I want to be able to make 3D and contour plots (with chosen levels) from a mathematical function.

For example,

```
phi = np.linspace(0,np.pi)
theta = np.linspace(0,np.pi)

D = np.sin(phi-theta)
```

where `D` is a 2D array, where each value of `phi` has an array made up of all `thetas`. Then to plot 3D, with the axes being `phi`, `theta`, and `D`. And a contour plot, where levels can be chosen from whatever value (with probably up to 10 levels, so, for instance, `phi` could be changed to `np.linspace(0,np.pi,10))`

How can I make such 3D and contour plots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a 3d plot, you'll want to create a meshgrid out of the `phi` and `theta` variables:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi)
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi)

Phi, Theta = np.meshgrid(phi, theta)
```

From here you can go ahead and compute `D` and make your plot:

```
D = np.sin(Phi - Theta)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(Phi, Theta, D)
```

Which gives the following surface plot:

[image]

Contours aren't much more work (though aren't particularly illuminating for a simple sine function):

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.contour(Phi, Theta, D)
```

[image]